# Android: Context is null when passed to method

Tags: java, android

In my application class InboxTabFragment is instantiate as like below:

InboxTabFragment.java

```
public class InboxFragmentTab extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private static final Uri SMS_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
private static final Uri SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(SMS_CONTENT_URI, "inbox");
private static final String COLUMNS[] = new String[] {"person", "address", "body", "date", "type"};

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_layout, container, false);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this.getActivity(), SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI, COLUMNS,
            null, null, null);
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
    ArrayList<Sms> result = new ArrayList<Sms>();

    if(c!=null) {
        for(boolean hasData = c.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData=c.moveToNext()){
            boolean isSent = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("type")) == 2;
            String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));

            String sender = ContactManager.getContactName(context, address);
            String receiver = "Me";

            Sms sms = new Sms(address, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")), new Date(Long.parseLong(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")))), isSent ? sender : receiver);
            sms.setSender(isSent ? receiver : sender);
            result.add(sms);
        }
    }
    SmsAdapter adapter = new SmsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, result);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

Problem occurs in line:

```
String sender = ContactManager.getContactName(context, address);
```

Context passed in method parameter is null and I have no idea how to deal with this.
I'll be grateful if someone would like to help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Try to pass `getActivity()` instead of `context`

Comment: Use `getApplicationContext()` or your Activity class's `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning at value to the `context` object. Add:

`context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();`